# HTML/CSS tables are not aligning correctly on eBay listing

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a nice looking ebay listing, and although the html looks fine outside of eBay, the tables seem to break and mis-align after being previewed/posted on eBay.

This is what it looks like previewed in Chrome

[image]

This is what it looks like previewed in the eBay preview box:

[image]

Of course this isn't the full listing but everything else seems to align correctly except those parts.

```html
<table id="Table1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/K2yWDPk.png" width="920" height="25" border="0" alt="Top Shadow">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">
        <a href="STORELINK">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5u3mlVA.png" border="0" alt="Logo" width="230" height="100">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" border="0">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LkCBdLv.png" height="100" width="230">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4" background="http://i.imgur.com/4xTnFGE.png" width="460" height="50">
        <div id="Table1Links">
          <a href="STORELINK">Store</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" background="http://i.imgur.com/Mm6XcLE.png" width="460" height="50">
        <form name="search" method="get" action="http://search.stores.ebay.com/search/search.dll" target="_blank">
          <!-- Replace with # with STOREID -->
          <input name="sid" value="#REPLACEWITHSTOREID" type="hidden">
          <input name="srchdesc" value="y" type="hidden">
          <input name="fp" value="0" type="hidden">
          <input name="query" size="30" maxlength="300" type="text">
          <input value="Search Store" name="submit" src="http://i.imgur.com/0uSF8nO.png" type="image">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to dumb down the HTML as much as possible and then use an inline stylesheet to style the elements.

Comment: Do they allow CSS backgrounds?

Comment: They do, but I don't think you can do them inline like that, been a while since I spent that much time on an eBay listing :P

Comment: How would I go about dumbing it down? I can't get around using rowspan for certain elements without it breaking completely, although I see other listings utilize it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the style sheet in the ebay template its self right at the beginning of the code in `<style></style>` tags.

Then add this code to your styles

```
    #mainpage {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then change the table tag to this. This works for me. Let me know if it works or you need any help or if want any more information.

```
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" id=mainpage border=1 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 cols=5>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because eBay adds all those annoying "`&nbsp;`" tags in where formatted code is spaced - try unformatting the code (yes, take out all the tabs/spaces manually and just use the enter key to separate stuff).

I literally just went through this - and was pissed after finding out that it wasn't aligning correctly - but since I "unformatted" the code (I had at least a million   tags in mine after submitting to eBay), things are flowing how they should be - and none of those tags are generated anywhere!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listing and preview in other browsers? Seems Chrome displays CSS in eBay previews quite wrongly. It's unuseable to list on eBay IMHO.

Example:

http://community.ebay.com/t5/Technical-Issues/CSS-error-when-listing-with-Chrome/m-p/23635402